# Firebase newData.val() not being used to check if child exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am checking to see if a username is already in use before creating a new users account and if its not write the new username to the 'usernamelist' database, but when I use the database rule `!root.child('usernamelist').child(newData.val()).exists()` it doesn't allow me to write new data, but if I use `!root.child('usernamelist').child('testuser01').exists()` it works, it seems like the `newData.val()` is not using the newData for the child name for some reason.

I have also tried using:

```
!root.child('usernamelist').hasChild(newData.val())
!data.hasChild(newData.val())
```

Here is the full code im using and my database and rules:

'usernamelist' database:

```
{
 "usernamelist" : {
 "testuser01" : "testuser01",
 "testuser02" : "testuser02",
 "testuser03" : "testuser03",
 "testuser04" : "testuser04",
 "testuser05" : "testuser05"
  },
}
```

Database rules:

```
{
"rules": {

 "usernamelist": {
   ".read": "auth != false",
   ".write": "auth != false 
   && newData.exists()
   && !root.child('usernamelist').child(newData.val()).exists()",
  },

 }
}
```

Code im using to add the data:

```
firebase.database().ref('usernamelist').update ({
 [username]: username,
})
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: The existing data is available in `data`. Have you tried just: `newData.exists() && !data.exists()`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the answer to why .child(newData.val()) doesnt work but I guess I have settled for a work around for now(see below). Please let me know if you find an answer to your original question.

Workaround I used: !root.child('usernamelist/'+newData.val()).exists()